# react-native : how to do conditional network request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, react-native

I am using [random user api](https://randomuser.me/api?results=10) for my react native project. This is what I want to do:

Check if the `randomUserapi` has the user name that I want to find, and if yes, display the user's email using the `get request`

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet, View, } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios'


export default class TestScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName1: 'ronja',
      userName2: 'mathys',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api?results=10')
          .then(response => console.log(response.data.results))
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>

      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>userName1: {this.state.userName1} </Text>

// here I want check if random user api has name 'ronja' if yes, find the email and display

        <Text>email: </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>userName2: {this.state.userName2} </Text>
        <Text>email: </Text>
      </View>

    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't stated a question. What's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to find the user name that matches my state and display their email address!

Comment: you need to enumerate the `response.data.results` and find the username with the one you have in your state. then you could just update state with email and show in the render

Comment: @Shubhank thanks for the comment! Could you please explain in code? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: it's quite long and would be spoon feeding, you could drop to the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) if you need more understanding.